# Can I use the Hungarian algorithm to find max cost?

Tags: algorithm, hungarian-algorithm

The Hungarian algorithm solves the assignment problem in polynomial time. Given  workers and tasks, and an n×n matrix containing the cost of assigning each worker to a task, it can find the cost minimizing assignment.

I want to find the choice for which cost is max? Can I do it using Hungarian or any similar method? Or this can only be done exponentially?

Comment: @2er0 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As David said in the comment:

```
Multiply the cost matrix by -1 for maximization.
```

Answer (score 11):

Wikipedia says:

> If the goal is to find the assignment that yields the maximum cost,
>   the problem can be altered to fit the setting by replacing each cost
>   with the maximum cost subtracted by the cost.

So if I understand correctly: among all the costs you have as input, you find the maximum value. Then you replace each cost `x` by `max - x`. This way you still have positive costs and you can run the Hungarian algorithm.

Said differently: Hungarian tries to minimize the assignment cost. So, if you are looking for the maximum, you can reverse the costs: x -> -x. However, some implementations (don't know if all or any) require positive numbers. So the idea is to add a constant value to each cost in order to have positive numbers. This constant value does not change the resulting affectation.

Comment: can u explain with an example?

Comment: @UtxD see my last edit. What don't you understand? I don't have the time right now to write a full example and I don't feel it's necessary.

Comment: The Wikipedia entry says that you need nonnegative costs, but that's probably not true for most implementations (though the resulting monotonicity property is convenient for the analysis).

Comment: (So just multiply the cost matrix by -1 for maximization.)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I have edited my answer. I don't remember the details of this algorithm so I don't know if it's really mandatory but it's nothing to add a constant value to all costs (and does not change the affectation). You can always remove that cost at the end if you need the cost value too.