# Finding an optimal selection in a 2D matrix with given constrains

Tags: algorithm, performance, search, optimization

## Problem statement

Given a **m x n** matrix where **m <= n** you have to select entries so that their sum is maximal.

- However you can only select **one entry per row** and **at most one per column**.
- The performance is also a huge factor which means its ok to find selections that are not optimal in oder to reduce complexity *(as long as its better than selecting random entries)*

## Example

- Valid selections:

  [image: valid] [image: valid empty col]
- Invalid selections:
  *(one entry per row and at most one per column)*

  [image: invalid empty row and row dublicate] [image: invalid dublicate col]

## My Approaches

1. Select best of k random permutations

   ```
   A = createRandomMatrix(m,n)
   selections = list()

   for try in range(k):
     cols = createRandomIndexPermutation(m) # with no dublicates
     for row in range(m):
       sum += A[row, cols[row]]
       selections.append(sum)

   result = max(selections)
   ```

   This appoach performs poorly when **n** is significantly larger than **m**
2. Best possible (not yet taken) column per row

   ```
   A = createRandomMatrix(m,n)
   takenCols = set()

   result = 0
   for row in range(m):
     col = getMaxColPossible(row, takenCols, A)
     result += A[row, col]
     takenCols.add(col)
   ```

   This approach always values the rows *(or columns)* higher that were discovered first which could lead to worse than average results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds exactly like the **rectangular linear assignment problem** (RLAP). This problem can be efficiently (in terms of asymptotic complexity; somewhat around cubic time) solved (to a global-optimum) and a lot of software is available.

The basic approaches are LAP + dummy-vars, LAP-modifications or more general algorithms like network-flows (min-cost max-flow).

You can start with ([pdf](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2008/10/2115.pdf)):

> Bijsterbosch, J., and A. Volgenant. "Solving the Rectangular assignment problem and applications." Annals of Operations Research 181.1 (2010): 443-462.

Small python-example using python's common scientific-stack:

**Edit:** as mentioned in the comments, negating the cost-matrix (which i did, motivated by the LP-description) is not what's done in the Munkres/Hungarian-method literature. The strategy is to build a profit-matrix from the cost-matrix, which is now reflected in the example. This approach will lead to a non-negative cost-matrix (sometimes assumes; if it's important, depends on the implementation). More information is available in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520691/can-i-use-the-hungarian-algorithm-to-find-max-cost).

#### Code

```python
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as sopt    # RLAP solver
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # visualizatiion
import seaborn as sns            # """
np.random.seed(1)

# Example data from
# https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html
# removed a row; will be shuffled to make it more interesting!
harvest = np.array([[0.8, 2.4, 2.5, 3.9, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0],
                    [2.4, 0.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.7, 0.0, 0.0],
                    [1.1, 2.4, 0.8, 4.3, 1.9, 4.4, 0.0],
                    [0.6, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0, 3.1, 0.0, 0.0],
                    [0.7, 1.7, 0.6, 2.6, 2.2, 6.2, 0.0],
                    [1.3, 1.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.2, 5.1]],)
harvest = harvest[:, np.random.permutation(harvest.shape[1])]

# scipy: linear_sum_assignment -> able to take rectangular-problem!
# assumption: minimize -> cost-matrix to profit-matrix:
#                         remove original cost from maximum-costs
#                         Kuhn, Harold W.:
#                         "Variants of the Hungarian method for assignment problems."
max_cost = np.amax(harvest)
harvest_profit = max_cost - harvest

row_ind, col_ind = sopt.linear_sum_assignment(harvest_profit)
sol_map = np.zeros(harvest.shape, dtype=bool)
sol_map[row_ind, col_ind] = True

# Visualize
f, ax = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(9, 6))
sns.heatmap(harvest, annot=True, linewidths=.5, ax=ax[0], cbar=False,
            linecolor='black', cmap="YlGnBu")
sns.heatmap(harvest, annot=True, mask=~sol_map, linewidths=.5, ax=ax[1],
            linecolor='black', cbar=False, cmap="YlGnBu")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, this is exactly what I'm looking for! I'm wondering however if negating the cost matrix could break the [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). When searching for solutions that maximize rather than minimize, people tend to subtract each entry from the maximum value and dont negate the cost matrix.

Comment: That's actually a very good point. I was somewhat careless and took the LP-formulation as the one to work with, while the solver is Munkres-based.